# BLOB type With Spring-Data-JPA

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I  hava a JPA query defined in a JpaRepository:

```
List<Object[]> getDoc ();
```

one of the columns if a `BLOB type`

but when I do:

```
System.out.println("Content Type -> " + obj[1].getClass());
System.out.println("Content  -> " + obj[1]);
```

I got:

```
Content Type -> class [B
Content  -> [B@73e73b8e
```

and I don't know how to convert it to String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is that your `obj[1]` is an array of bytes, which is exactly what it should be for a blob.

To convert it into a string, you need to specify the encoding. Assuming the data is encoded according to UTF-8, that would be

```
String s = new String((byte[]) obj[1], StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```